# Visual Studio 2013 Update 4, Duplicate Entries in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, solution-explorer

We are working on a enterprise application where we have multiple projects in our solution. Since update 4 many files are duplicated in the solution explorer.

I have removed them, but after next build (with nant) all files are duplicated again.

any suggestions how i can permanently remove the duplicates?

[image: Solution Explorer]

***Web.csproj File:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{5EB1EC4C-47BA-49DF-91C3-3A5266835A02}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Ilogs.Products.Modules.DMS.Web</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Ilogs.Products.Modules.DMS.Web</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <IISExpressSSLPort />
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>..\..\..\EDP\Web\bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Ext.Net">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\lib\Ext.Net\1.7\Ext.Net.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Base.Common.FF, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\lib\Ilogs.BaseWeb\2.3.0.0\Net4.0\Ilogs.Base.Common.FF.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Base.Common.ResourceManagement, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\lib\Ilogs.BaseWeb\2.3.0.0\Net4.0\Ilogs.Base.Common.ResourceManagement.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Base.Data.Common, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\lib\Ilogs.BaseWeb\2.3.0.0\Net4.0\Ilogs.Base.Data.Common.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Base.Data.NHibernate, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\lib\Ilogs.BaseWeb\2.3.0.0\Net4.0\Ilogs.Base.Data.NHibernate.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Base.Gis, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\lib\Ilogs.BaseWeb\2.3.0.0\Net4.0\Ilogs.Base.Gis.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Base.Model.Core.Interfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\lib\Ilogs.BaseWeb\2.3.0.0\Net4.0\Ilogs.Base.Model.Core.Interfaces.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.BaseWeb.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\lib\Ilogs.BaseWeb\2.3.0.0\Net4.0\Ilogs.BaseWeb.Core.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.BaseWeb.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\lib\Ilogs.BaseWeb\2.3.0.0\Net4.0\Ilogs.BaseWeb.Data.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.BaseWeb.GUI.ExtNet.Components, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\lib\Ilogs.BaseWeb\2.3.0.0\Net4.0\Ilogs.BaseWeb.GUI.ExtNet.Components.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Products.Base.Code, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\productsweb\EDP\Web\bin\Ilogs.Products.Base.Code.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Products.Base.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\productsweb\EDP\Web\bin\Ilogs.Products.Base.Model.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Products.Base.Resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\EDP\Web\bin\Ilogs.Products.Base.Resources.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Products.EDP.Components, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\EDP\Web\bin\Ilogs.Products.EDP.Components.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Products.EDP.Config, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\EDP\Web\bin\Ilogs.Products.EDP.Config.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Products.EDP.Controller, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\EDP\Web\Bin\Ilogs.Products.EDP.Controller.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Products.EDP.Web">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\EDP\Web\bin\Ilogs.Products.EDP.Web.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Products.Mocca.Reports, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\EDP\Web\bin\Ilogs.Products.Mocca.Reports.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Products.Modules.DMS.Interfaces">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\EDP\Web\bin\Ilogs.Products.Modules.DMS.Interfaces.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Products.Moment.Common, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\productsweb\EDP\Web\bin\Ilogs.Products.Moment.Common.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Products.Moment.Data.Model, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\EDP\Web\bin\Ilogs.Products.Moment.Data.Model.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Products.Moment.Data.ModelSource, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\EDP\Web\bin\Ilogs.Products.Moment.Data.ModelSource.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ilogs.Products.Moment.Data.ModelSource.Gui, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\EDP\Web\bin\Ilogs.Products.Moment.Data.ModelSource.Gui.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.JScript" />
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\lib\Ext.Net\1.7\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NHibernate, Version=3.2.1.4000, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\lib\NHibernate\3.3.4.0\NHibernate.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Stimulsoft.Base, Version=2013.3.1800.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ebe6666cba19647a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\lib\Stimulsoft\2013.3.1800\Stimulsoft.Base.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Stimulsoft.Report, Version=2013.3.1800.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ebe6666cba19647a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\lib\Stimulsoft\2013.3.1800\Stimulsoft.Report.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\lib\Microsoft\AspNet\WebApi\Client\5.2.0\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\lib\Microsoft\AspNet\WebApi\Core\5.2.0\net45\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Application\app.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\model\Readme.md" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\store\Readme.md" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\view\common\ActionGlyphs.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\css\application.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Application\css\application.scss" />
    <Content Include="Application\css\Variables.css">
      <DependentUpon>Variables.scss</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Application\css\Variables.scss" />
    <Content Include="Application\css\Variables.css.map">
      <DependentUpon>Variables.css</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <None Include="Web.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="Web.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Application\app\Application.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\config\Runtime.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\model\DocItemModel.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\model\DocItemTreeModel.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\model\DocTagModel.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\model\DocTypeModel.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\proxy\CustomAjaxProxy.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\store\DocItemStore.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\store\DocItemTreeStore.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\store\DocTagStore.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\store\DocTypeStore.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\view\content\Content.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\view\content\ContentController.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\view\content\ContentModel.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\view\content\ContextMenu.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\view\content\EditWindow.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\view\content\UploadWindow.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\view\main\Main.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\view\main\MainController.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\view\main\MainModel.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\view\navigation\ContextMenu.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\view\navigation\Navigation.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\view\toolbar\DocTagWindow.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\view\toolbar\DocTypeWindow.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\view\toolbar\MenuToolbar.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\view\toolbar\MenuToolbarController.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\app\view\toolbar\MenuToolbarModel.js" />
    <Content Include="Application\css\application.css" />
    <Content Include="Application\images\icons\filetypeDoc.png" />
    <Content Include="Application\images\icons\filetypeImg.png" />
    <Content Include="Application\images\icons\filetypePdf.png" />
    <Content Include="Application\images\icons\filetypeTxt.png" />
    <Content Include="Application\images\icons\filetypeUnknown.png" />
    <Content Include="Application\images\icons\filetypeXls.png" />
    <Content Include="Application\index.html" />
    <Content Include="Pages\CustomerDmsTab.aspx" />
    <Content Include="Pages\EmployeeDmsTab.aspx" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\FileSaver.js" />
    <Content Include="Web.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Infrastructure\CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Pages\CustomerDmsTab.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CustomerDmsTab.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Pages\CustomerDmsTab.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>CustomerDmsTab.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Pages\EmployeeDmsTab.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>EmployeeDmsTab.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Pages\EmployeeDmsTab.aspx.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>EmployeeDmsTab.aspx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Service\CustomerPhotoController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Service\DocItemController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Service\DocItemListController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Service\DocItemTreeController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Service\DocTagController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Service\DocTypeController.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Application\app\view\ribbon\" />
    <Folder Include="Controller\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>56864</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost:56864/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
  <ItemGroup>
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\Application.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\config\Runtime.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\model\DocItemModel.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\model\DocItemTreeModel.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\model\DocTagModel.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\model\DocTypeModel.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\proxy\CustomAjaxProxy.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\store\DocItemStore.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\store\DocItemTreeStore.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\store\DocTagStore.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\store\DocTypeStore.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\view\common\ActionGlyphs.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\view\content\Content.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\view\content\ContentController.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\view\content\ContentModel.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\view\content\ContextMenu.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\view\content\EditWindow.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\view\content\UploadWindow.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\view\main\Main.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\view\main\MainController.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\view\main\MainModel.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\view\navigation\ContextMenu.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\view\navigation\Navigation.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\view\toolbar\DocTagWindow.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\view\toolbar\DocTypeWindow.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\view\toolbar\MenuToolbar.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\view\toolbar\MenuToolbarController.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\view\toolbar\MenuToolbarModel.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Scripts\FileSaver.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\css\application.css" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\css\application.css.map" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\css\Variables.css" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\css\Variables.css.map" />
    <SourceFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.png" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Pages\CustomerDmsTab.aspx" />
    <SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Pages\EmployeeDmsTab.aspx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(SourceFiles->'%(MSBuildProjectDirectory)..\..\..\EDP\Web\Modules\DMS\Web\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Visual Studio has changed the relative path of all files to absolute.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <SourceFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.html" />
    <SourceFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.css*" />
    <SourceFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.png" />
    <SourceFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.js" />
    <SourceFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\*.as?x" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(SourceFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(SourceFiles->'%(MSBuildProjectDirectory)..\..\..\EDP\Web\Modules\DMS\Web\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the project name (not the solution) -> Unload project.
Right click on the project name again -> Edit {ProjectName}.cproj

Look for the `<ItemGroup>` containing entries like: `<Compile Include="Runtime.js" />`

Remove duplicate entries. Save, close.
Right click on the project name again -> Reload project.

Comment: I have two sections: One with this entries
<SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app\config\Runtime.js" />

and one with this entries

<Content Include="Application\app\config\Runtime.js" />

There is no ItemGroup for the JS Files with <Compile ...

No duplicates in the other Groups

Comment: I'm pretty sure the section with the `<SourceFiles` and absolute paths was created by your build tool, as there is an AfterBuild event that references them. I think Visual Studio displays them as entries in solution explorer.

Comment: THX, I have removed the after build event and the extra itemgroup. i need another solution for the after build task ^^

Comment: Maybe try leaving them, but use another name as identifier. Instead of `<SourceFiles Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app.js" />` try `<FilesToDeploy Include="C:\svn\branches\Mocca-EDP-3.3.0.0\productsweb\Modules\DMS\Web\Application\app.js" />` and then in the AfterBuild event: `<Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToDeploy)" DestinationFiles="@(FilesToDeploy->'%(MSBuildProjectDirectory)..\..\..\EDP\Web\Modules\DMS\Web\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />`

Comment: In my case (Windows Forms, VS 2013) the duplicated items appeared in the top-level form only. There was no sign of duplication in the csproj file. Unloading and reloading the project as suggested by @atika fixed it. No doubt it will happen again but I haven't yet tracked down what triggers it.